# Syntax highlighting for Lua in LuaEclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lua

How do I turn syntax highlighting on in Eclipse editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LuaEclipse 1.2 in Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu 11.04 (64-bit), Lua syntax highlighting seems to enable automatically as long as the file extension is `.lua`. I don't see a way to turn it off or on.

Comment: I have Windows 7 32bit with Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Just tried this on Windows 7 64-bit but with Eclipse Indigo 32-bit (and JRE 6 u27, 32-bit). I get the same behavior as Ubuntu (syntax is auto enabled based on file extension). I right-clicked my project, chose **Lua Actions > New Lua File**. Then, I entered `local testvar` and observed the **`local`** keyword changed color from black to purple.